# VLOOKUP not looking the correct information up

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a table in google sheets with 4 sheets in the same table. the details table contains the student ID, first name and second name but I would like to lookup the scanned number from the attendance table however the student number needs to match the scanned number.

the student number and the scanned number are both in the attendance table but I would like the scanned number to go into the details table according to the matched student number.

I have tried the following VLOOKUP but I am just getting errors.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B), VLOOKUP(B2:B,'Student Attendance'!A:F,2,FALSE),))
```

so in sheet 1 I have scanned number in column B and Student number in column D which is entered through an app. on sheet 2 i have already got the student ID but i would like to lookup the scanned number from sheet 1 and enter accordingly against the correct student ID

I have tried using:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B,'Student Attendance'!A:F,2,TRUE),)
```

however this is only printing the same scanned number for every unique student number entered.

example data:

**attendance sheet:**

```
timestamp,             scanned number,        class,          student number

time/date              BARCODE-SCANNED        Subject              123456
time/date              BARCODE-SCANNED1       Subject              621314
```

this is all entered through an app so nothing manual here.

**details sheet:**

```
scanned number,             student number,            name 

BARCODE-SCANNED                  123456             Student name 
BARCODE-SCANNED1                 621314             Student name
```

on this sheet the student number and the name is already inputted manually but i would like to get the scanned number from the first sheet according to the student number. at the moment i have only got student number and name in this sheet.

Comment: I have tried using what you have stated but I am still getting the same error. I am using the array formula because I dont want the spreadsheet to create a new row when new data is added from the google sheet form.

Comment: Please don't tag Google sheets questions with the Excel tag - they're not the same thing and Excel has no "ArrayFormula"

Comment: Ok sorry about that I am using Google sheets.

Comment: Can you set up a sample spreadsheet and share it here ? That way we can see how your data is structured. That would greatly improve the chance of getting correct help.

Comment: I have added a sample example to what i would like the spreadsheet to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA (IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B,{'Student Attendance'!D:D, 'Student Attendance'!B:B},2,TRUE),))
```

The vlookup value should always be in the first column of the lookup range.

Comment: I have tried using the formula suggested by you but i am getting an error “Formula parse error” however when i use:
    =ARRAYFORMULA (IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B,{'Student Attendance'!A:F},2,TRUE),))
i get the scanned number to come in but it is the same for all the records when it should be unique upon checking the student number.

Comment: That's exactly why it is always useful to provide an example spreadsheet. I edited my formula. Can you try again ?

Comment: With the new code there is nothing looked up in the scanned number column on the details sheet. I have update the original post with images from the actual spreadsheet.

Comment: Seems like the first column should be 'Student Attendance'!D:D instead of 'Student Attendance'!F:F ? Try that ?

Comment: I have made that change but i am having the same problem but now it only looks up one student and not the other students. You can see the results above. Although that scanned number displaying it is the incorrect number as it is the other students number.

Comment: Please share a copy.. there is no way I can troubleshoot like this. Erase or change any sensitive data if needed.

Comment: Thanks after a bit of time playing around with your solution i have managed to get it to work.

Comment: Ok. Glad to hear ! :-)

Comment: I would like to ask is there a way to make this column fixed so for example once it has looked up the number can it permanently store it as a value without having to rely on the first sheet.

Comment: In that case you'd either have to copy and paste as values only or use a google apps script.